# Cordova/Ionic is stacking up AJAX data in Android's Data space

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, ionic-framework

**EDIT: I've got the solution after trying out things. Refer this answer of mine here**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28496743/4412363

My application contains multiple templates, which are populated with data received using AJAX requests, and I am using Ionic framework with AngularJS. And I noticed that each time data is being received, it adds up to the application's **Data**.

I predicted it could be something about DOM, but even after commenting out the part which appends to (or modifies) DOM, the data still added up to my app's Data. So I am 99% sure Cordova is saving the requested data **not** in cache, but in Data. So what could be the solution? I tried:
`data = null` on success, but I suppose it'd treat it as a var, rather than an object?

PS: A simple Cordova+jQuery mobile application without Ionic framework had the same issue.

Cordova Version: android 3.6.4

A sample of how I'm retrieving the data:

```
fileURL = "https://s3-xxxxx" + parameter + ".html";
var fileRequest = $.ajax({
    url: fileURL,
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    async: true
});
```